# What does mean this notation after the P?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

[image]

It looks like small capital letter lambda, Λ. What is its purpose?

Comment: See Wedge product: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_product

Comment: Where did you find this? What was the context?

Comment: @WillJagy, it is from Multivariate Analyses course. It wants me to prove that transpose of A is A.

Answer (score 3):

The $\Lambda$ refers to a diagonal matrix with positive, or at least non-negative, entries.

On second thought, to get both equals signs to make sense, it needs to be $A$ that is the diagonal matrix, $P$ is an orthogonal matrix and $P'$ its transpose, so $P P' = I. $ So $\Lambda$ is symmetric non-negative. Then $e_i$ is a column vector with mostly $0$ entries and a single $1$ in position $i,$ and $e_i e_i'$ is the square matrix  with mostly $0$ entries and a single $1$ in position $ii.$